# unable to fetch record in django using list

Tags: django

View code:
below is my view code function through which I want to retrieve details of user in list.

```
def followingview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        uid= request.session.get('uid')
        ufg= userfollowing.objects.filter(userno_id=uid)
        flist=[]
        for i in ufg:
           flist.append(i.following_id)
           print(flist)
        urr= User.objects.filter(id=(flist))
        context={'ufg':ufg,'ur':urr}
        return render(request,'following.html',context)
```

Html Code:

```
<li class="text-center">

{%for j in urr%}
<h4 class="text-capitalize">UserName: {{j.username}}</h4>
<p class="text-muted text-capitalize">FirstName: {{j.first_name}}</p>
<p class="text-muted text-capitalize">LastName: {{j.last_name}}</p>                   
{%endfor%}

</li>
```

Model:

```
class userfollowing(models.Model):
  userno= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  following_id= models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Can you please share your `userfollowing` model?

Comment: I shared my model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter with the [**`__in`** lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
urr= User.objects.filter(id__in=flist)
```

That being said, you can effectively filter with if we make the `following_id` a `ForeignKey`, so:

```
class userfollowing(models.Model):
    userno= models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='followees'
    )
    following = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='follows'
    )
```

then we can query with:

```
urr = User.objects.filter(follows__userno_id=uid)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`userfollowing`</s> to `UserFollowing`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: urr= User.objects.filter(id__in=flist). I tried this but this also fetching single record.

Comment: @RaviMishra:  exactly how does the `flist` looks like? Are you sure all numbers map to a `User` (this is one of the *many* reasons to *not* work with an `IntegerField`, since it does not guarantee referential integrity.